# Arithmetic operation overflow while reading socket in C#

Tags: c#, sockets, websocket, buffer

So i decided to start learning it by giving myself some interesting task.
As a web developer i wanted to have my very own WebSocket server.
So i've written it but it only accepts the first request. After that there is Arithmetic operation onverflow.
Here is some code for you to see what am i doing wrong :S I'm really out of ideas.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Threading;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using System.Security.Cryptography;

using WebSocket.Utils;

namespace WebSocket
{
    class SocketReader
    {
        public EndPoint ipAddr { get; set; }
        private Socket userSocket;
        private byte[] buffer;
        private string SOCKET_GUID = "258EAFA5-E914-47DA-95CA-C5AB0DC85B11";

        public SocketReader(Socket socket)
        {
            userSocket = socket;
            ipAddr = socket.RemoteEndPoint;
            Read();
        }

        private void Read()
        {
            //Read packet size
            buffer = new byte[2];
            userSocket.BeginReceive(buffer, 0, 2, SocketFlags.None, ReadCallbackStatic, null);
        }

        private void ReadCallbackStatic(IAsyncResult ar)
        {
            try
            {
                if (userSocket.EndReceive(ar) >= 1)
                {
                    int bufferSize = BitConverter.ToInt16(buffer, 0);
                    buffer = new byte[bufferSize - 2];
                    //Read Packet
                    userSocket.BeginReceive(buffer, 0, buffer.Length, SocketFlags.None, ReadCallback, null);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception se)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Something blew on ReadCallbackStatic");
                Console.WriteLine(se.Message);
                Console.WriteLine(se.StackTrace);
                Disconnect();
            }
        }

        private void ReadCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
        {
            try
            {
                //Copy the buffer so we can receive the next packet ASAP
                byte[] buff = new byte[buffer.Length];
                Array.Copy(buffer, buff, buffer.Length);
                Read();

                string handshakeStr = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(buff);
                string[] list = Regex.Split(handshakeStr, "\r\n");

                //Sec-WebSocket-Key: S5o6fCVLRMJhdXTF3H9w3Q==
                //Sec-WebSocket-Version: 8

                string key = "";
                string clientProtocol = "0";

                foreach (string str in list)
                {
                    if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(str)) { continue; }
                    if (str.Length > 20 && str.Substring(0, 19) == "Sec-WebSocket-Key: ")
                    {
                        key = str.Substring(19);
                        continue;
                    }

                    if (str.Length > 20 && str.Substring(0, 23) == "Sec-WebSocket-Version: ")
                    {
                        clientProtocol = str.Substring(23);
                        continue;
                    }
                }

                if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(key))
                {
                    Disconnect();
                }

                SHA1 shaEnc = new SHA1CryptoServiceProvider();

                byte[] byteString = ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(key + SOCKET_GUID);
                byte[] hash = shaEnc.ComputeHash(byteString, 0, byteString.Length);
                string acceptKey = Convert.ToBase64String(hash);

                List<string> headers = new List<string>();
                headers.Add("HTTP/1.1 101 Switching Protocols");
                headers.Add("Upgrade: websocket");
                headers.Add("Connection: Upgrade");
                headers.Add("Sec-WebSocket-Accept: " + acceptKey);

                foreach (string header in headers)
                {
                    SendString(header + "\r\n");
                }

                Console.WriteLine(acceptKey);

                SendString("\r\n");

            }
            catch (SocketException se)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Something blew on ReadCallback");
                Console.WriteLine(se.Message);
                Disconnect();
            }
        }

        private void SendString(string str)
        {
            userSocket.Send(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(str));
        }

        private void Disconnect()
        {
            userSocket.Disconnect(false);
            Console.WriteLine("Client with ip {0} Disconnected", ipAddr);
        }
    }
}
```

It's shortened version of my class but the problem that is bugging me appears in "ReadCallbackStatic" on this line:

```
buffer = new byte[bufferSize - 2];
```

i really don't know what am i doing wrong :S. 
The thing is that ... i actually handshake properly but then when i sent some information from the client to my server this exception is thrown

I did some debugging and it appears that somehow the buffer variable becomes negative number O.O

Comment: Are you sure you're supposed to subtract 2?

Comment: To echo harold's point - a length marker doesn't usually include the size of the length marker; meaning: if the marker (length 2) reports 200 bytes, I would expect to read an *additional* 2 bytes, so 202 in total.

Answer (score 2):

My guess would be that you're blowing up when the MSB is set, i.e. maybe the client is sending a number >= 32768 and < 65536, which (via your `ToInt16`) is becoming a large negative 16-bit number (or, alternatively, throwing an arithmetic overflow issue). I would try using `ToUInt16` instead.

To be honest, you really don't need `BitConverter` here; depending on the endianness this is either:

```
int bufferSize = (buffer[0] << 8) | buffer[1];
```

or

```
int bufferSize = buffer[0] | (buffer[1] << 8);
```

Comment: It works with UInt convert now it doesn't throw exception but it gives pretty huge buffer size so when i log it in the console i can't actually see it cuz there are too many blank new lines. 
I guess i'll have to log it on file to see what is going on or just breakpoint debug it

Comment: @Sk1ppeR only your wire-spec can tell you what the correct interpretation is. Note that 65k is not particularly big in any way, and in many cases your buffer can be a lot smaller than the data (the idea being: you read it in chunks).

Answer (score 0):

I believe problem could be in case when buffer contains of zero numbers, so:

```
  int bufferSize = BitConverter.ToInt16(buffer, 0); // 0
  buffer = new byte[bufferSize - 2];  // 0 - 2 == -2
```

Which results in the overflow exception whilst executing `new byte[-2]`

I do not know the logic behind your code but I believe you should allocate a new buffer considering `buffer.Length` value

Comment: It's the same without the substract too and yes the packet length is 2 bytes. The funny thing is that bufferSize is more like "-3550" not just 0 :/

Here is console output
 "17735
0pV0tDprwlXs6BqAshUb+0MPobg=
-30079"
The first number is the handshake string. The second is something else :(

The mambo jambo string is the acceptKey used to handshake with the client (in this case Google Chrome)

Comment: @Sk1ppeR see my answer; -3550 would map to 61986 if it is a MSB issue, and -30079 would map to 35457

Comment: @Sk1ppeR : any way it is dangerous to allocate buffer in this way, you may get an other Buffer overflow exception in some day. So before doing `bufferSize - 2` check whether `bufferSize <= 2` or refer to the inbound buffer.Length value